# Run Event at Startup

Tags: mysql, scheduler

Is there a way to run an event at startup either using Event Scheduler or Task Scheduler?

I have a main mysql server that stores information for a website. If that site goes down, I have a backup website and mysql server. When the main site comes back online, I want to run code that would update the main mysql DB with what was done on the backup mysql DB. Is this possible?